# Is there a word for a medical person who only does one proceedure?

Tags: single-word-requests, medical

A word for a medical person who specializes in one specific proceedure within a medical specialty?

Comment: A ***specialist***?

Comment: I was going to say a proctologist.

Comment: @HotLicks - ouch.  I’m picturing Chevy Chase singing Moon River.

Comment: circumcisologist ?

Answer (score 2):

A subspecialist is a specialist of a subspecialty. In medicine you'll find subspecialization in several specialties. In cardiology, for instante, you have the electrophysiologist (the EPS guy), the cardiovascular pathologist, the arrhythmologist, the Lipid Specialist, etc.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspecialty):

> A subspecialty or subspeciality (British English) is a narrow field within a specialty such as forensic pathology, which is a subspecialty of anatomical pathology. A subspecialist is a specialist of a subspecialty. In medicine, subspecialization is particularly common in internal medicine, cardiology, and neurology, and has grown as medicine has
>   become more complex.